# Universal VBA Word Count for Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to create a universal, error resistant VBA code that would count words in selected ranges as MS Word does. This below is the best I could do and I was hoping that somebody would have a look and let me know if I missed something or suggest any improvements. The code is quite fast and works with single cell, non-adjacent cells and whole columns, I need it to be as universal as possible. I'll be looking forward to feedback.

```
Option Explicit

Sub word_count()


Dim r() As Variant 'array
Dim c As Long 'total counter
Dim i As Long

Dim l As Long 'string lenght
Dim c_ch As Long 'character counter
Dim c_s As String 'string variable
Dim cell As range
Dim rng As range

If Selection Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Sorry, you need to select a cell/range first", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
ElseIf InStr(1, Selection.Address, ":", vbTextCompare) = 0 And InStr(1, Selection.Address, ",", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then  'for when only one cell is selected

    word_count_f Selection.Value, c
    MsgBox "Your selected cell '" & Replace(Selection.Address, "$", "") & "' in '" & Selection.Parent.Name & "' has " & c & " words."
    Exit Sub

ElseIf InStr(1, Selection.Address, ",", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then 'when user selects more than one cell by clicking one by one -> address looks like ('A1,A2,A3') etc

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim help() As Variant
    ReDim help(1 To Selection.Cells.Count)
    i = 1
    For Each cell In Selection 'loading straigh to array wouldn't work, so I create a helper array
        help(i) = cell.Value
        i = i + 1
    Next cell

    r = help

Else 'load selection to array to improve speed

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    r = Selection.Value

End If

Dim item As Variant

For Each item In r

    word_count_f item, c

Next item


MsgBox "Your selected range '" & Replace(Selection.Address, "$", "") & "' in '" & Selection.Parent.Name & "' has " & c & " words."

End Sub

Private Function word_count_f(ByVal item As Variant, ByRef c As Long)

Dim l As Long 'lenght variable
Dim c_s As String 'whole string variable
Dim c_ch As Long 'characted count variable

    l = Len(item)
    If l = 0 Then Exit Function
    c_s = item
    c_s = Trim(c_s)

    Do While InStr(1, c_s, "  ", vbTextCompare) > 0 'remove double spaces to improve accuracy
        c_s = Replace(c_s, "  ", " ")
    Loop

    If InStr(1, c_s, " ", vbTextCompare) = 0 And l > 0 Then 'if there was just one word in the cell
        c = c + 1
    ElseIf InStr(1, c_s, " ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then 'else loop through string to count words

        For c_ch = 1 To l 'loop through charactes of the string
            If (Mid(c_s, c_ch, 1)) = " " Then
                c = c + 1 'for each word
            End If
        Next c_ch
        c = c + 1 'add one for the first word in cell
    Else 'hopefully useless msgbox, but I wanted to be sure to inform the user correctly
        MsgBox "Sorry, there was an error while processing one of the cells, the result might not be accurate", vbCritical
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: This kind of question should be posted at [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/excel+vba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in a similar way but with less code if you are interested to see?:

```
Sub word_count()
    start_time = Timer
    Dim r As Variant 'temp split array
    Dim arr As Variant 'array
    Dim c As Long 'total counter

    If Selection Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Sorry, you need to select a cell/range first", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    Else
        c = 0
        For Each partial_selection In Split(Selection.Address, ",")

            If Range(partial_selection).Cells.Count > 1 Then
                arr = Range(partial_selection).Value
            Else
                Set arr = Range(partial_selection)
                'single cell selected don't convert to array
            End If

            For Each temp_cell In arr
                If Len(Trim(temp_cell)) > 0 Then
                    r = Split(temp_cell, " ")
                    For Each temp_word In r
                        If Len(Trim(temp_word)) > 0 Then
                            c = c + 1
                            'If the word is just a blank space don't count
                        End If
                    Next

                    'c = c + (UBound(r) - LBound(r) + 1)

                    'trimmed = Trim(temp_cell)
                    'c = c + 1 + (Len(trimmed) - Len(Replace(trimmed, " ", "")))
                Else 'Blank cell
                    'Do nothing
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End If

    Dim item As Variant

    time_taken = Round(Timer - start_time, 3)

    MsgBox "Your selected range '" & Replace(Selection.Address, "$", "") _
        & "' in '" & Selection.Parent.Name & "' has " & c & " words." _
        & vbNewLine & "Time Taken: " & time_taken & " secs"

        Debug.Print c & " in "; time_taken; " secs"

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, it's the code is much shorter, more elegant and even a little faster. May I just ask where there is the '- LBound(r)' part, when the lbound is always going to be 0? Thank you.

Comment: Hi Papaniks, you are right, `LBound(r)` will be zero, this is just me typing out of habbit `UBound - LBound` as not all arrays are zero indexed. You can Dim an array like `Dim arr(5 To 10)` if you like and so the `UBound - LBound` is more robust to these edge cases so it's just a habit I got in to. If my answer solves your question then please consider marking it as the accepted answer and voting it up. thanks.

Comment: We could speed it up by copying the selection to an array and looping through the array instead.

Comment: Thank you for the update and the explations, It runs really great! The solution from Nathan_Sav with the 'l = l + (Len(s) - Len(Replace(s, " ", "")))' seems even faster (about 50 %) though.

To copy the selection to an array to work with non adjacent cells (where the address is A1,B2,C3...), there must be an if condition, to treat it differently from A1:C3, or is there a better way?

Comment: Please see the way I would approach it (updated answer). `For Each partial_selection In Split(Selection.Address, ",")` then each loop copy the range to the array `arr = Range(partial_selection).Value` - let me know what you think.

Comment: Actually, we would need to loop the split array r and ensure that there were no blank words. For example Nathan_Sav's answer here would miscount `'word_one (space) (space) word_two'` as more than two words if there is more than one space between the words. See my solution here looping the split array r.

Comment: File here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_8k_2KV8F_cR3osWYAxGanq7wlBU7k_R/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hey, sorry it took me so long to reply, but your answer after the edits is perfect. It's reliable, works no matter how the user selects the cells, doesn't count double spaces as separate words and it's super-fast. Thank you for all the effort!

Comment: My Pleasure St3ve :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this sort of approach?  There may be the need to check for the next character to the space being another space, which would need some additions made.  To detect `word  one` as being the same as `word one` in the count.  Also, transferring the range to an array would make it a touch faster.

```
Function Word_Count(rng As Excel.Range) As Long

Dim c As Excel.Range
Dim s As String
Dim l As Long

For Each c In rng.Cells

    s = Trim(c.Value)

    If s <> "" Then
        If InStr(1, s, " ") > 0 Then
            '   Find number of spaces.  You can use the ubound of split maybe here instead
            l = l + (Len(s) - Len(Replace(s, " ", "")))
        Else
        End If
        '   Will always be 1 word
        l = l + 1
    End If

Next c

Word_Count = l

Set c = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: This is incredible, it's like 3 time faster when processing a big set of data and the solution is really elegant. Thank you! Changing it to array made an 1/3 improvement when processing a lot of text. I added loop from my original solution to remove any potential double spaces (do while instr "  ": replace "  ": " " loop). Can you think of any better solutions, or is this the only way?

Comment: `application.Evaluate("=SUM(LEN(N1:N5)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(N1:N5,"" "",""""))+1)")`

Comment: There is an edge case not accounted for. If the cell has a string with more than one space between two words like 'word_one (space) (space) word_two' this method `l + (Len(s) - Len(Replace(s, " ", "")))` would count more than 2 words. See my solution below for one way to handle this edge case.

Comment: @AlexL Hi, I did add that to the answer.  It was not really clear how they were to be as no example data was shown.  This was a start approach :)

Comment: Nathan_Sav, sorry I missed that in your text! Too eager to look at code :) Yeah I agree.